# What are the effects of Happiness?

Tags: banished

Various items and events raise and lower the happiness of your villagers. Besides achievements, what gameplay effects does low or high happiness bestow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happiness makes your workers more productive. Specifically they idle less often.

[Source](http://banished-wiki.com/wiki/Citizens#Happiness)

Comment: Do you know by how much?

Comment: No, the dev didn't do a very good job of making it clear how much impact various effects have on productivity. However if you want a source, its the in-game help